# Mongo 3.2. Document max size 16Mb - is this value for compressed (snappy) document or not?

Tags: mongodb, limit

From docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/
the maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

I wonder how mongo checks this limit.
If I use WiredTiger and snappy compression, does it mean that I can put more data inside document until it reached 16Mb. Or Mongo calculates size of document in uncompressed state?

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB enforces the 16MB limit even before passing the document to the storage engine, so no, you cannot use the compression to squeeze more data into the document.

[Reference](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/15339cv0tq/do-we-have-a-document-size-limit-of-16mb-when-using-wired-tiger-engine).

Answer (score 1):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot
>   use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount
>   of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB
>   provides the GridFS API.